# Error when using awk command to trim sequence files

Tags: rna-seq, fastq, linux, awk, read-correction

I am attempting to edit my `fastq` sequence files with an `awk` command from a published article. The sequence files are all contained in one directory where I am running the `awk` command from the terminal in a Linux environment. There are 4 fastq files in the directory

```
01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.fastq
01_thu163_IX_RNA_001.fastq
01_thu164_IX_RNA_001.fastq
01_thu190_IX_RNA_001.fastq
```

I would like to trim all these files at once with the `awk` command so I wrote this `for` loop:

```
for filename in ./*.fastq*
do
awk -v s=10 -v e= 40 ' {if (NR%2 == 0) print substr ($0, s+1, length ($0)-s-e); else print $0;} ' ./${filename} >  ./${filename}_trimmed
done
```

However, I am getting the following error:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file ` {if (NR%2 == 0) print substr ($0, s+1, length ($0)-s-e); else print $0;} ' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I then thought maybe it was an error with the `for` loop so I tried the command as per the instructions in the article

```
awk -v s=10 -v e= 40 '{if (NR%2 == 0) print substr ($0, s+1, length ($0)-s-e); else print $0;}' ./01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.fastq > ./Trim_01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.fastq
```

But this also produced the same error:

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `{if (NR%2 == 0) print substr ($0, s+1, length ($0)-s-e); else print $0;}' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

I have checked the syntax for the `awk` command and it should be correct. Could anyone please give me advice as to what I am doing wrong and how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You have a whitespace here:

```
e= 40
```

awk thinks that 40 is your rule and the rest of the line is a filename.

Comment: Thank you very much really appreciate it, I didn't notice that. Will give it a try now again.